# About equivalence between geometric vector bundles and locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of finite rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a last question about the book by Wedhorn/Görtz (Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes), chapter 11 (on vector bundles).

They define first the quasi coherent bundle defined by $\mathcal{E}$ as follows: (see definition 11.2 and proposition 11.3):

[image]

The objective is now to prove an equivalence between geometric vector bundles and locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules of rank $n$ (see definition 11.5 for how they define a geometric vector bundle over a scheme $X$):

[image]

I don't quite understand how from the reasoning above, it follows that $\mathbb{V} (\mathcal{E})$ is a geometric bundle of rank $n$? I understand that we have these isomorphisms $c: \mathcal{E}_{|U} \xrightarrow{\sim} (\mathcal{O}_{U}^{n})^{\vee}$. Does he now apply the fact from earlier, i.e. that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X} (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{E}) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_X (\mathbb{V} (\mathcal{E}), \mathbb{V} (\mathcal{F}))$ is injective? i.e. does he apply the functor $\mathbb{V}$ to the above isomorphisms?

Here is also the converse direction:

[image]

I understand that we may assume that $V = \mathbb{V} (( \mathcal{O}_X^n)^{\vee})$. However, I don't understand how from proposition 11.3 it follows that then $\mathscr{S}(V/X) = \mathcal{O}_X^{n}$??

Also, how can one prove the equation (11.4.1), i.e. that $$ f^{*} \mathscr{S} (V/X) = \mathscr{S} ((V \times_X X^{'})/ X^{'}) $$

Comment: 1. I've replaced $\mathcal{F}$ (\mathcal{F}) with $\mathscr{S}$ (\mathscr{S}) to make your equations at the end actually match the text. 2. Somehow the answers to all of your questions are "apply the definitions" with a dash of "work locally enough". I think you can get to some of these answers just by knowing you're on the right track, but if that's not happening, some more detail on exactly where you're stuck would help us set you on the right path.

Comment: Dear @Kamil, I've noticed you placed a bounty on this question. I'd be happy to answer this and help you clear up your confusions if you detail a little more about where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: @KReiser, I think my questions in the post are fairly detailed. For example, I do not understand why $\mathscr{S}(V/X) = \mathcal{O}_X^{n}$.

Comment: Perhaps I was imprecise: I'm curious about where you get stuck when you try to prove these things on your own. You say "I do not understand" but you don't explain what you've tried and where that fails.